# C# Array of Increments

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, loops, increment

If I want to generate an array that goes from 1 to 6 and increments by .01, what is the most efficient way to do this?

What I want is an array, with mins and maxs subject to change later...like this: `x[1,1.01,1.02,1.03...]`

Comment: What about to use a loop with decimal value?

Comment: Define efficient...  least code?  Or fastest?

Comment: increment by .01 the values inside the array? or increment the size of the array by 1?

Comment: If you mean fastest then hard-code it (assuming min/max/increment don't change).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming a `start`, `end` and an `increment` value, you can abstract this further:

```
Enumerable
    .Repeat(start, (int)((end - start) / increment) + 1)
    .Select((tr, ti) => tr + (increment * ti))
    .ToList()
```

Let's break it down:

`Enumerable.Repeat` takes a starting number, repeats for a given number of elements, and returns an enumerable (a collection). In this case, we start with the `start` element, find the difference between `start` and `end` and divide it by the `increment` (this gives us the number of increments between `start` and `end`) and add one to include the original number. This should give us the number of elements to use. Just be warned that since the `increment` is a decimal/double, there might be rounding errors when you cast to an int.

`Select` transforms all elements of an enumerable given a specific selector function. In this case, we're taking the number that was generated and the index, and adding the original number with the index multiplied by the increment.

Finally, the call to `ToList` will save the collection into memory.

If you find yourself using this often, then you can create a method to do this for you:

```
public static List<decimal> RangeIncrement(decimal start, decimal end, decimal increment)
{
    return Enumerable
        .Repeat(start, (int)((end - start) / increment) + 1)
        .Select((tr, ti) => tr + (increment * ti))
        .ToList()
}
```

Edit: Changed to using Repeat, so that non-whole number values will still be maintained. Also, there's no error checking being done here, so you should make sure to check that `increment` is not 0 and that `start` < `end * sign(increment`). The reason for multiplying end by the sign of increment is that if you're incrementing by a negative number, end should be before start.

Comment: +1 for actually showing where the numbers come from (and for using `decimal`).

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
double[] result = Enumerable.Range(100, 500)
                  .Select(i => (double)i/100)
                  .ToArray();
```

(hence efficient in terms of readability and lines of code)

Comment: Good answer.  One correction: the range you want is Enumerable.Range(100, 600).

Comment: You should probably base all of the numbers off of the start, end, and increment, rather than calculating them all before hand and sticking magic numbers into the code.

Comment: @jdmcnair: Corrected, although your `Range(100, 600)` would be a range from 1 to 7. Note that above excludes `6.00`, if you need it take 501.

Comment: `doubles` are evil for things like this, even when rounded. It's fixed decimal precicion, use a `decimal`

Comment: What happens if the user wants to start with a non-integral number? IE: 0.01 to 0.5 using 0.002 increments?

Comment: if you divide by 100 rather than multiplying by 0.01, you don't need to call Math.Round().

Answer (score 5):

I would just make a simple function.

```
    public IEnumerable<decimal> GetValues(decimal start, decimal end, decimal increment)
    {
        for (decimal i = start; i <= end; i += increment)
            yield return i;
    }
```

Then you can turn that into an array, query it, or do whatever you want with it.

```
        decimal[] result1 = GetValues(1.0m, 6.0m, .01m).ToArray();
        List<decimal> result2 = GetValues(1.0m, 6.0m, .01m).ToList();
        List<decimal> result3 = GetValues(1.0m, 6.0m, .01m).Where(d => d > 3 && d < 4).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this solution the best, as it is simply and has very little overhead compared to using LINQ (don't have to enumerate the collection twice, first to build the Enumerable with Range/Repeat, second for the Select function).

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop with 0.01 increments:

```
List<decimal> myList = new List<decimal>();

for (decimal i = 1; i <= 6; i+=0.01)
{
  myList.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Elegant**

```
double[] v = Enumerable.Range(1, 600).Select(x => x * 0.01).ToArray();
```

**Efficient**

```
Use for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't use a floating point datatype (like `double`), they don't work for things like this on behalf of rounding behaviour. Go for either a `decimal`, or integers with a factor. For the latter:

```
Decimal[] decs = new Decimal[500];
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
  decs[i] = (new Decimal(i) / 100)+1 ;
}
```

Comment: don't agree with "whatever you do, don't use floating point datatype" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: I was going for the more traditional 'binary floating point' definition of floating point ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this. The solution method returns a double array

```
double[] Solution(double min, int length, double increment)
{
    double[] arr = new double[length];
    double value = min;
    arr[0] = value;
    for (int i = 1; i<length; i++)
    {
        value += increment;
        arr[i] = value;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var ia = new float[500]; //guesstimate
var x = 0;
for(float i =1; i <6.01; i+= 0.01){
    ia[x] = i;
    x++;
}
```

You could multi-thread this for speed, but it's probably not worth the overhead unless you plan on running this on a really really slow processor.

Comment: But I can't access `ia` outside the loop, can I? Isn't this a scope issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, ia was not defined inside the loop therefore it's is scope is not limited to inside the loop

Comment: First: that doesn't fit in that array. Second, the implicit narrowing conversion doesn't work, you need  i += 0.01F for this, third, you'll start getting rounding errors at 1.52