# Looping from a position in array +2 a certain amount of times, getting those values and display (later to plot graph)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio, .net-3.5

Similar to this: [C# Array of Increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721247/c-sharp-array-of-increments)
I've also looked at this: [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/c-sharp-arrays-getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array)

I calculate a sum to achieve my value from a position in my array, for instance I want to decode to a float position 502 in my byte array and increment the position by 2 so I would be looking at position 504, 506, 508 etc. a specified amount of time like 100 times (so 100 values). So I thought using a for loop may be best, please note I can retrieve the first value just need to get the rest. **I need to step through and retrieve three different variables, not just the one.**

I've seen this around (have never used it) and think the '+= 2' is the steps?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) { }
```

At the moment I have something like (This just gets me the first value, no idea how to increment position)

```
int of2 = 502;
int of1 = 254;
int of3 = 750;

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) 
{
    float f1 =  Decode(Rec, of1) / (float)100;
    float f2 =  Decode(Rec, of2) / (float)100;
    float f3 =  Decode(Rec, of3);
}
```

The end result should look like:-

Structure

*(f1, f2, f3)*

*(f1, f2, f3)*

*(f1, f2, f3)*

[image]

Comment: So do you want to increment all 3 values on each iteration?

Comment: Yes and although each have different positions, I want to increment +2 on each of them

Comment: It is not clear what you exactly want to achieve. Can you at least write down the results of the first 3 steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope thats what you want:

```
int of2 = 502;
int of1 = 254;
int of3 = 750;

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) 
{
    float f1 =  Decode(Rec, of1) / (float)100;
    float f2 =  Decode(Rec, of2) / (float)100;
    float f3 =  Decode(Rec, of3);
    of1 +=2;
    of2 +=2;
    of3 +=2;

}
```

Comment: This looks good to me, I will try it thanks! Do you know how to, for example, display all values? I'm not too great with loops. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Well obviously depends on the kind of app. In a console app just put Console.Writeline(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",of1,of2,of3   ))